# Python Flask: how to build a template via a function that is not a route

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build a side navigation and import it into a base html file.

The code in `base.html` looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>hello</p>

    {% include 'sidenav.html' %}

  </body>
</html>
```

I then have a file that builds the navigation via code. The relevant code is here:

```
## sidenav.py

import os

from flask import Flask, render_template

from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader

def build():
    env = Environment(loader = BaseLoader())
    t = env.get_template('sidenav.html')
```

then `__init__.py` has this:

```
import os

from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    from .layout.sidenav import build
    build()
```

I get `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: sidenav.html`

It doesn't matter if I place `sidenav.py` at the same level as `__init__.py` or in a subfolder. I get the same error.

I'm hoping it is possible to build this sidenav without passing all the arguments via routes. I'm not sure how I would approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
import os

from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader


def render_example():
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'templates')  # or set full path to templates folder
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(path))

    template = env.get_template('base.html')
    print(template.render())


render_example()
```

Templates must be placed in `./templates` folder